# How can I write a piece of Java an code that checks if any character of a string is convertible to an integer between 0 and 9?

Tags: java, string, integer, parsing-error

How can I write a piece of Java code that checks if a string is convertible to an integer, that is if any character of it is convertible to an integer between 0 and 9 ? I thought of something like this:

```
String s = "...";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)

{

    int h = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));
    if (h < 0 || h > 9)
        throw new IntegerFormatException();   
}

catch (IntegerFormatException e)

{

    System.out.println("This is not an integer");

}
```

where IntegerFormat Exception is something like

```
public class IntegerFormatException extends Exception

{

    public IntegerFormatException()
    {
        super ("This string isn't convertible to  an integer");
    }
    public IntegerFormatException(String message)
    {
        super (message);
    }

}
```

But if I then try the code with, say, "8&35" as the string I don't get my message "This is not an integer", but I get and IDE automatic red ink message stating

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "&"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at project.pkg9.pkg2.Project92.main(Project92.java:60)
```

Java Result: 1

Is my code wrong ? If yes, how can I fix it ? Many thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: 1. `s.substring(i, i + 1)` -> [`s.charAt(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) 2. You can use [`Character.isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) to check (or write your own method which performs a similar check, given knowledge of what values digits are encoded as in a `char`)

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 4):

There is already a run time exception for that, use it!

```
String s = "8&35";
try {
    int result = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("This is parsable: " + result);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("s is  NOT parsable....");
}
```

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `Integer.parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` exception if you try to parse something that's not an int, and you don't catch that in your try/catch block. You could catch that in your catch block or use a regex to check what the character is at that location before you try to parse (or, as pointed out in the comments, `Character.isDigit()`).

Also, there's no need to see if a single digit is less than 0 or greater than 9 - how could a single digit *possibly* be anything but an integer in the range of 0 - 9? This won't really tell you if the character is a valid `int` or not because, unless you're comparing the ASCII values, it doesn't make sense to talk about whether & is greater than 9, for example.

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with a Regex :

```
if(s.matches("[0-9]"))
{
    //it's an Integer, 
    //execute logic
}
```

Comment: what about negative integers ?

Comment: @svasa `^-|[0-9]` as regex will do it. test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/2qzjol/2)

Comment: @svasa If the OP is only looking at one character at a time, the negative sign will be disregarded anyway.

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping you can use regex. This will work and would throw the `IntegerFormatException` for an empty string as well.

```
String s = "...";

if (!s.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    throw new IntegerFormatException();
}
```

It won't cover `Integer` type capacity overflow - I mean a huge number above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Not sure do you need that though.

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));` throw an exception by itself.

In particular, it throws the `java.lang.NumberFormatException:` which is not caught by your catch.

If you really need to use your exception (there is already one so why not to use that one?) use the following instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1234/&&56";

    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)

        {

            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int h = c-'0';
            
            if (h < 0 || h > 9)
                throw new IntegerFormatException();   
        }



    }catch(IntegerFormatException e)
    {

        System.out.println("This is not an integer");

    }
}
```

Note that you should also include the check for the very first character (it could be the `-` sign) in the case you are trying to parse `signed` numbers.

Comment: It's worth noting that the IntegerFormatException can't occur.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If it's a single-digit int, it couldn't possibly be less than 0 or greater than 9. (It can't be negative either if you're only looking at a single character).

Comment: Oh yes, the code above just shows why the `IntegerFormatException` wasn't raised at all. It is not a sound check for a string to be convertible to an Integer.

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the documentation for the `Integer.parseInt(String s)` method.  The full header for this method is `public static int valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException` and the documentation states that the `NumberFormatException` is thrown when the string does not contain a parsable integer.

To obtain the functionality you described, you should consider that passing a single char into the function will always result in an integer from 0 to 9 (inclusive) if the char is parsable to an int, so, your if statement is probably unecessary.  To make your implementation work, you should catch the `NumberFormatException` and use that to determine if the char parsed correctly.

Also, to simplify your code, you can also use the `s.charAt(i)` method rather than `s.substring(i, i + 1)`.  You might also want to look into regex to obtain the behavior you explained.

Comment: How is that different than my answer?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I suppose that it's not, but I was writing my response prior to you posting yours, so I did not see your response.

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String regex = "^-?[0-9]+$";
if (s.matches(regex) {
    // it's a number  
} else {
   // not a number
}
```

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Character class isdigit api or other api to test if it is digit or not

```
String s = "1234/&&56";
         for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
             char ch=s.charAt(i);
             if((Character.isDigit(ch))){
                 System.out.println(ch);
             }
         }
```

Comment: I thank everyone of you very much. All your answers are clear and decisìve. I'll use them profitably. Thank you all again.

Answer (score -2):

The function chr($i) returns a one-character string that contains the character equivalent of $i, where $i is an integer between 0 and 255.